# Selecting data via mysqli

Tags: php

i keep getting this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

and non of the other answers for this issue you will solve my issue. any idea what the problem is here?

```
<?
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","mysql");

$data = 'SELECT * FROM `league_quiz` ORDER BY score';
$result = $link->query($data);
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['leaguename'] . " " . $row['quizscore'];
echo "<br/>";

}
$link->close ();
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure those username and password "" aren't blank?

Comment: I've rarely seen a mysql user who has no username.  I would then believe that is why your connection is returning false.

Comment: they are not blank! i just made them in here, i'm sure they are correct.

Comment: @user3130214 And we'd know that, how?  I mean, if there was something there, the least you could do is let us know by maybe filling it with asterisks.  Secondly, you don't check for any errors, aside from the parsing bit..  So debug some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step of solving any problem is to understand it.

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function `fetch_assoc()` on a non-object

In simpler language: you're trying to use the method `fetch_assoc()` on something that isn't an object, specifically `$result`. So there's your problem: `$result` isn't an object.

So how may this be? You assign it here

```
$result = $link->query($data);
```

So that means your query must be failing. To see the error, you can try to print `mysqli_error($link)`.

And in the future, always check whether your commands execute succesfully, e.g.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  printf("Error during connection: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  return false;
}
```

And later

```
if (!$result) {
  printf("Error during querying: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  return false;
}
```

Or something similar, depending on your exact code.